# chart not updating after changing the chart options

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Im very new to highcharts and javascript so please bear with me. I have a bar chart and i want to create a button in which the data is sorted from greatest to least netPL.

```
var chart2 = $('#container2').highcharts() <! –– an existing bar chart ––> 

document.getElementById('sortbutton').addEventListener('click', () => {
   
  chart2.series[0].userOptions.dataSorting = {matchByName:true,enabled:true};
  chart2.update();


});
```

the values of the settings were changed from false to true but it doesn't translated on chart

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the data sorting feature modifies the original data array and currently it can't be used in a dynamic way.

Reported issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13033

---

As a solution, you can write your own function for sorting:

```
function getData() {
    return [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175];
}

function getSortedData() {
    return getData().sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a
    });
}

var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: getData()
    }]
});

document.getElementById('sorted').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chart.series[0].setData(getSortedData());
});

document.getElementById('unsorted').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chart.series[0].setData(getData());
});
```

---

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ruLvajk9/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData